# Literature review on the design and implementation of two factor authentication for user login

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, google-2fa

How do I write the literature review of 'design and implementation of two factor authentication for user login'

I've been stuck in gathering information. I don't even know how to proceed. I don't know how to make use of the materials I've gathered.